# How to query an unknown solr instance for its solr-spec from the command line

Tags: solr

I have inherited a big compressed archive file containing a solr instance of uncertain origin. If I unpack it on my linux box and want to find out what version it is, is there a better way than starting it up with bin/solr start etc.?

When I start solr up the dashboard knows what its solr-spec is; can I find out what it is from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the library jars have a version string embedded in the name. So, just grep the file list for *solr-*.jar*

Oh, and if you have *bin/solr*, you already must be on Solr 4.10+ or Solr 5. Before that, you started by doing *java -jar start.jar* in the example directory.

Comment: I think this turned out to be as good as can be hoped for at the moment; I was hoping for e.g. `$ bin/solr version` but that's not supported at the moment.